# Server 2012 R2 on a single server running AD and DNS

Tags: networking, dns

Is it possible to configure the DNS server to get to both external and internal domains with the same name? Have an ISP handling web site with the same domain name as my internal domain. DNS server apparently points to the external web site address.  Thus I cannot add a new user workstation ( System 7 Pro ) to the network, because the DNS is pointing to the external address and I get the cannot find the DNS server error.   Not sure what I did but initially I could add workstations but could not get to external web site.  Made changes and now able to get to website but now find I cannot add users to local domain. And not sure how I managed to do either. Thanks

Comment: Can you provide examples of some of the internal names that match external names?

Comment: The intranet and internet domain name is alumatecpp.com.  Basically we have a website www.alumatecpp.com being hosted externally at 1and1.com.  Unfortunately the local domain was also named alumatecpp.com.  When I do an NSlookup of alumatecpp.com from the DNS server it returns the 1and1 assigned IP address.  Thus when attempting to add a client PC to the local domain I get a DNS error.

Answer (score 0):

The quick answer is no, I believe you have the wrong idea on how DNS works.

But it is possible if you do it right.  This is called Split DNS.  The trick is to include ALL names from the externally-hosted view in your internal view on the AD side, i.e., maintain the external view on the ISP nameservers as a proper subset of your internal view.  You have to add any new names to both views.  The IP addresses can be different internally vs externally (e.g., public vs. 10/8 space, NAT'd vs non-NAT'd), but the names must all exist internally so they are resolvable internally.

This is likely the source of your trouble / misconception.  DNS looks for an answer internally and a response of "that name doesn't exists" is a valid answer and doesn't cause fallback to look at the external DNS servers.  This is why the external view must be a proper subset of the internal set of names for this to work correctly with no surprises.

Comment: I may have explained my problem incorrectly. I do realize that my local DNS server looks for an answer internally and the answer it is providing is the external address to my website (74.168.172.10). Thus when I am adding a new PC to my local domain it can't see my local domain. How do I force the DNS server to recognize the network address for the internal domain (192.168.1.2).  I have attempted to add a new zone with internal domain associated with the internal address.

Comment: I have no idea how exactly you are trying to configure this.  Provide examples / screenshots.